# Asp.Net Mvc - "Completed" is appended to my action name and gives InvalidOperationException Could not locate a method named 'XXXCompleted'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddVideoAsync(string permaLinkFixed)
{
     return Json(new { Success = true });
}
```

When I call this action, I get this error :
`InvalidOperationException -  Could not locate a method named 'AddVideoCompleted' on controller type YYY.`

No matter what I call the action, I get the same error.  If I call it `AddVideoCompletedAsync` I get an error for `AddVideoCompletedCompleted`

As I was typing my question and after having searched for an answer for hours, I finally realized the answer, posted below.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the Action name ends with `Async`.  You can't have this if your action doesn't return `Task<ActionResult>`. (The method was async before but manually removed it and forgot to change the name)

Removing Async from `AddVideoAsync` to `AddVideo` solved the problem